# SQLite GROUP_BY doesn't maintain data order

Tags: database, sqlite

If I have names like this in database

```
A
C
D
B
```

If I use `group by` keyword why sqlite give data like this

```
A
B
C
D
```

I mean why does it return data sequentially ?? I don't need to maintain sequence. is there any way to maintain original format by using `group by`

Answer (score 3):

To expand on TokenMacGuy's answer:

A real database can have hundreds of tables, each with thousands of rows, each having a variable number of rows.  The database software (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) manages where and how each of these items are stored in memory.  Let's say that there is a table whose rows are stored in three different places in the hard drive.  When you do a `SELECT` statement on that table, and you don't have `ORDER BY`, the database software grabs the appropriate rows and shoves them into the output.

SQLite is different - the file is generally smaller, generally local.  When you do a `SELECT` statement on a table in SQLite, the information is likely stored in the same place.  To quote the [sqlite language specification](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby),
"If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined."   Notice that the language specification does *not* guarantee that the rows *won't* be in order.

Long story short, *the `GROUP BY` only changes which rows show*, **not** what order those rows are returned in.  Try creating multiple tables, and inserting to them in different orders, at different times, then running your `SELECT` again.  It will likely not be in order this time.

Answer (score 2):

Rows in databases are not *in* any particular order, and they are not returned in any particular order.

That is, unless you provide an `order by` clause in your query.